# Debugging Powershell with VS 2017.7.6 broken? How to?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a number of Powershell cmdlets that form a relatively complex module. I have done so in the past, but this time a number of thing are changed...

- I can not get a breakpoint to work. SOmehow VS does not seem to autoamtically want to connect to Powershell or Powershell Core runtime environments.
- The Module is a class library that is made using the netstnadard2.0
- Executable is set as

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

- Arguments are

> -NoLogo -NoExit -Command "Import-Module '.\Cli.dll'"

All works nice - Powershell windows opens, but breakpoints do not load. Period. Executing a Cmdlet also does not load them. I am attached to SOMETHING because i offers "detach from process".